# Problema con programa copiar y sustituir cadena en C

Tags: c

a ver si me podéis ayudar con esto.

Estoy tratando de montar un programa en C que genere un buscar y reemplazar de una segunda cadena en la cadena principal.
Adjunto código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//Escribir un algoritmo para determinar si una subcadena especificada ocurre en una cadena dada, y si es así, escribir un asterisco (*) en la primera posición de cada ocurrencia.

int main(){
    //Definimos un array de timpo char que va a contener un máximo de 100 caracteres
    char str[100];
    
    //Cremos algunas variables
    char ch;
    int i;
    
    //Pedimos al usuario que introduzca una palabra
    printf("\n Introduce la cadena inicial :  ");
    //Guardamos la palabra dentro del array, llamado str
    gets(str);
    
    //Pedimos al usario que caracter dentro de la palabra, pedida anteriormente, queiere substituir
    printf("\n Introduce el caracter que quieres sustituir :  ");
    //Guardamos este caracter dentro de la variable ch
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    
    getchar();
    
    //Bucle for encargado de recorrer todo la palabra, guardad en el array str
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++){
        
        //Condicional if, que valora si algún caracter de la palabra coicide con el caracter que quiere substituir el usuario
        if(str[i] == ch){
            //Si coiciden los caracteres, lo vamos a substituir por un #
            str[i] = '#';
        }
    }
    //Imprimimos la nueva palabra creada
    printf("\n El resultado de sustituir '%c' por * = %s ", ch, str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Problema, si introduzco un solo caracter, sustituye bien, pero si es una cadena de más de 1 caracter, sigue sustituyendo el primer caracter.

Por ejemplo: "laboratorio"
Sustituir: "or"
Por: "#"
Resultado: "lab#rat#ri#

Cuando debería ser "lab#rat#rio".
PD(Lo que quiero que se sustituya por "#" es el primer dígito de cada cadena en la que se concurra, no la cadena entera. Por ello indico que el resultado será "lab#rat#rio)

Alguien sabe que es lo que me puede estar fallando?
Gracias!

Comment: Si sustituto "or" en "laboratorio" el resultado debería ser "lab#at#io". Las "r" después de la "o" también desaparecen.

Comment: perdón, no me explique bien. Lo que quiero que se sustituya por "#" es el primer dígito de cada cadena en la que se concurra, no la cadena entera. Por ello indico que el resultado será "lab#rat#rio"

Answer (score 1):

Tal como Candid Moe señaló, el problema es que un char contiene sólo un caracter. Y aunque guardases la respuesta en un char[], tendrías que verificar cada uno de los caracteres de la segunda cadena.

Además de guardar la entrada del usuario en una cadena (como subst_str), el cambio principal sería más o menos así.

```
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++){
        
        //Condicional if, que valora si algún caracter de la palabra coincide con el caracter que quiere substituir el usuario
        for(j = 0; j <= strlen(subst_str); j++){
            if(str[i] == subst_str[j]){
                str[i] = '#';
            }
        }
    }
```

Ahora... Ya se la pregunta dice específicamente en C. Pero si no estás realmente limitado a C, sino que puedes usar C++, te recomiendo el uso de std::strings y algoritmos en tu código.

Por dos razones:

La primera es que hay muchas cosas que pueden facilitarte la vida (por ejemplo, podrías limitarte a un ciclo y utilizar std::replace https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/)

La segunda y que me resulta de mayor importancia: el manejo de memoria y los límites en los buffers. Siempre son el dolor de cabeza en todo programa. Un std::string se encarga del manejo de memoria por ti. Habrá quien diga: si eres cuidadoso no pasa. Mi experiencia (de ya más de 20 años) me dice que siempre habrá quien cometa un error.

Y para muestra un botón: tu código no tiene una "guarda" para asegurar que el usuario no escriba una cadena de un tamaño mayor a tu buffer.

Answer (score 0):

El detalle está en que si quieres sustituir una secuencia de letras, necesitas almacenarlas en un arreglo de caracteres. Tal como está el programa, recibe y busca sólo un caracter.

Además, dentro del ciclo `for` estás comparando sólo un caracter, cuando debes comparar subcadenas completas.

Este es el pgma con algunas mejoras. Entre otras cosas, por razones de seguridad usamos `fgets` para leer del teclado.

El texto a reemplazar ahora se lee en un arreglo de 10 posiciones; el tamaño se puede ajustar a lo que se necesite.

Pequeña complicación: la línea leida incluye el '\n' al final, del cual hay que deshacerse reemplazandolo con un '\0', lo que acorta la línea en una posición.

El cuerpo principal es un ciclo que recorre el texto original. En cada posición del texto compara lo que sigue del texto contra el texto de reemplazo usando `strncmp`. Si el texto se encuentra, se procede a reemplazar la primer letra del texto original con "#".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//Escribir un algoritmo para determinar si una subcadena especificada ocurre en una cadena dada, y si es así, escribir un asterisco (*) en la primera posición de cada ocurrencia.
int main(){
    //Definimos un array de timpo char que va a contener un máximo de 100 caracteres
    char str[100];
    
    //Cremos algunas variables
    char reemplazo[10];
    
    //Pedimos al usuario que introduzca una palabra
    printf("\n Introduce la cadena inicial :  ");
    //Guardamos la palabra dentro del array, llamado str
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    //Pedimos al usario que caracter dentro de la palabra, pedida anteriormente, queiere substituir
    printf("\n Introduce reemplazo :  ");
    //Guardamos este caracter dentro de la variable ch
    fgets(reemplazo, sizeof(reemplazo), stdin);
    
    //Bucle for encargado de recorrer todo la palabra, guardad en el array str
    int largo_texto = strlen(str) - 1;
    int largo_reemplazo = strlen(reemplazo) - 1;
    str[largo_texto] = 0;
    reemplazo[largo_reemplazo] = 0;
    
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= largo_texto - largo_reemplazo) {
        if (strncmp(str + i, reemplazo, largo_reemplazo) == 0) {
            str[i] = '#';
            i += largo_reemplazo;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n El resultado de sustituir '%s' por * = %s ", reemplazo, str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

produce:

```
 Introduce la cadena inicial :  la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta

 Introduce reemplazo :  in

 El resultado de sustituir 'in' por * = la mona jac#nta se ha puesto una c#nta
```

Comment: @George. Si, tengo un "}" demás. Mira la línea corregida.

Comment: Cierto! Muchas gracias.